# AWS solution for big CCTV System

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I´m researching AWS for a specific situation I need to solve. I have a customer that we provide a big CCTV solution. About 800 cameras. We are now trying to migrate part of this infraestructure to a cloud solution in AWS.

It is a big step replacing all in site storage they have to a cloud based solution.

I´ve been researching on the best solutions to take care of this and found that probably the best is to develop a solution that works with Amazon Storage Gateway.

The question is: does anyone know which is the most efficient way to deal with heavy video storage on AWS?. What is the recommended way to go?.

NOTE: Hope this question is not going to closed as too broad or opinion based. I know it is in the cutting edge of it.

Comment: If your main focus is getting video into AWS, then I'd investigate some previous re:Invent videos for media ingestion: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=aws+media+ingestion

Comment: What are the bandwidth and storage requirements for 800 cameras?

Answer (score 0):

IF you're looking for a very durable storage, the S3 is a very very good good option. It has 11 9's durability and then you can setup life cycle rules on it too.

Many companies including acloud guru host all their videos on S3. It has the ability to even be connected to 3rd party apps both inside AWS and outside.

Not to forget S3 has read after write consistency too. Also not only is it good for just storing but you can setup S3 efficiently for streaming videos too.